# Change Image Size From Uint8List Data in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, resize

I'm trying to change image size from uint8list data.

There are lots of Image classes in Flutter as you know,
and The final type of image I want to get is ui.Image.

I get Uint8List Image(.jpg) data from socket communication.
Now, I want to set the size of the image and get the Image of ui.Image at the end.

I tried to do that through (dart:ui : ui, package:image/image.dart : IMG)

```
IMG.Image img = IMG.decodeImage(data);
IMG.Image resized = IMG.copyResize(img, width: 400, height: 200);
ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(IMG.encodeJpg(resized));
ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
```

,but It freezes the app.

How can I do that? Is there any way? Thank you.

Additionally,
In "flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart",
`Image.memory(Uint8List, width, height)` can make it be easy to set image size.
Is there any way to get Uint8List from that Image widget?

Answer (score 11):

I resized the image data in Uint8List like below.

```
import package:image/image.dart as IMG

Uint8List resizeImage(Uint8List data) {
        Uint8List resizedData = data;
        IMG.Image img = IMG.decodeImage(data);
        IMG.Image resized = IMG.copyResize(img, width: img.width*2, height: img.height*2);
        resizedData = IMG.encodeJpg(resized);
        return resizedData;
     }
```

IMG : flutter image package

Comment: How to scale down 4k images on Web with that? It is too slow?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ui.decodeImageFromList` instead of `ui.instantiateImageCodec` and `getNextFrame()` ?

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

ui.decodeImageFromList(IMG.encodeJpg(resized), (ui.Image img) {
  // returned ui.Image
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I use the ui.Image img data, it shows invalid image data error.

Comment: did you call 'getNextFrame()' on result img ? @JaehyungKim

Comment: how this work while IMG.encodeJpg(resized) returns List<int>